# Set default value after parameter substitution with remove pattern

Tags: bash, shell, substitution

```
URL=example.com
#URL=example.com:8080

PORT=${URL#*:}
PORT=${PORT:-8080}
```

I want to do the parameter substitution with remove pattern and the default in one line.

Is the a way to set default when parameter substitution is empty?

Comment: Can you use zsh instead?

Answer (score 1):

For doing this in a one step in `bash`, you can use `read` with `IFS=:` with a default value appended to `url` variable like this:

```bash
url='example.com:7000'

IFS=: read host port _ <<< "$url:8080"

# check host and port values
declare -p host port
echo '------'

url='example.com'

IFS=: read host port _ <<< "$url:8080"

# check host and port values
declare -p host port
```

**Output:**

```bash
declare -- host="example.com"
declare -- port="7000"
------
declare -- host="example.com"
declare -- port="8080"
```

[Online Code Demo](https://ideone.com/mQ6yZm)

Comment: @MarkusWeigelt: Did this work out for you?

Comment: There are no *URL*! URL look like `httpx://example.com:12345/path`. Parsing this could be close to you answer, but...

Comment: But OP provided data is just `example.com`

Answer (score 0):

One option is:

```
[[ $url == *:* ]] && port=${url#*:} || port=8080
```

- See [Correct Bash and shell script variable capitalization](https://stackoverflow.com/q/673055/4154375) for an explanation of why I replaced `URL` and `PORT` with `url` and `port`.